# pecl installing for incorrect version of PHP

Tags: php, pecl, phpize

On a system running Unbuntu 16.04LTS, I'm trying to install the Sync class for PHP7.3.

phpinfo() on the system reveals the following:

```
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
...
PHP API => 20180731
PHP Extension => 20180731
Zend Extension => 320180731
Zend Extension Build => API320180731,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20180731,NTS
```

I installed the PHP7.3 dev tools (**apt install php7.3-dev**), and then set the following configurations:

```
sudo pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
sudo pecl config-set php_bin /usr/bin/php
```

When I install sync (**sudo pecl install sync**), it compiles for the wrong version of PHP.  The version pointed to by the indicated php file is 20180731, and as you can see in the log that follows, pecl makes everything for 20200930.

Of course, there is then an error message if I include the installed (**/usr/lib/php/20200930/sync.so**) extension:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sync: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20200930
PHP    compiled with module API=20180731
These options need to match
```

The pecl install log follows.  You can see that early on it's already set for the wrong version (**20200930**)...

```
> sudo pecl install sync
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading sync-1.1.2.tgz ...
Starting to download sync-1.1.2.tgz (16,785 bytes)
......done: 16,785 bytes
4 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20200930
Zend Module Api No:      20200930
Zend Extension Api No:   420200930
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/sync-1.1.2
running: /tmp/pear/temp/sync/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/20200930
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php/20200930
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking whether to enable synchronization object support (--enable-sync)... yes, shared
checking for shm_open in -pthread -lrt... yes
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... (cached) nawk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: patching config.h.in
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/sync-1.1.2/libtool --mode=compile cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/sync -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/sync-1.1.2/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/sync-1.1.2/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/sync -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2    -c /tmp/pear/temp/sync/sync.c -o sync.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/sync -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/sync-1.1.2/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/sync-1.1.2/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/sync -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/sync/sync.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/sync.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/sync-1.1.2/libtool --mode=link cc -shared -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/sync-1.1.2/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/sync-1.1.2/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/sync -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2    -o sync.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/sync-1.1.2/modules  sync.lo -lrt
libtool: link: cc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/sync.o   -lrt  -g -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,sync.so -o .libs/sync.so
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "sync.la" && ln -s "../sync.la" "sync.la" )
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/sync-1.1.2/libtool --mode=install cp ./sync.la /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/sync-1.1.2/modules
libtool: install: cp ./.libs/sync.so /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/sync-1.1.2/modules/sync.so
libtool: install: cp ./.libs/sync.lai /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/sync-1.1.2/modules/sync.la
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/sync-1.1.2/modules
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/sync-1.1.2/modules

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

running: make INSTALL_ROOT="/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/install-sync-1.1.2" install
Installing shared extensions:     /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/install-sync-1.1.2/usr/lib/php/20200930/
running: find "/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/install-sync-1.1.2" | xargs ls -dils
2113682   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 May 24 22:02 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/install-sync-1.1.2
2113703   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 May 24 22:02 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/install-sync-1.1.2/usr
2113704   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 May 24 22:02 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/install-sync-1.1.2/usr/lib
2113705   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 May 24 22:02 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/install-sync-1.1.2/usr/lib/php
2113706   4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 May 24 22:02 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/install-sync-1.1.2/usr/lib/php/20200930
2113702 108 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 107448 May 24 22:02 /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootHLMTSX/install-sync-1.1.2/usr/lib/php/20200930/sync.so

Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20200930/sync.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/sync-1.1.2
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=sync.so" to php.ini
```

I'm not familiar with pecl, and searches that have to do with pecl compiling for the wrong version are mostly old (php5 especially) or have to do with problems in the version.  I'm sure this is some configuration issue, but there's not much help (that I've seen) regarding controlling the compiler and versioning.

Any idea how I can make use of the PHP Sync class extension for PHP7.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 and beyond?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, another version of php-dev had been installed.  Here's what I did to clean it up:

```
sudo pecl uninstall sync
sudo apt remove php-dev
sudo apt remove php7.3-dev
sudo apt autoremove # <<< VERY important!
sudo apt install php7.3-dev
sudo pecl 
sudo pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
sudo pecl config-set php_bin /usr/bin/php
sudo pecl install sync
```

Now, SyncEvent() is working great on this system!